# Can you run only part of a script as sudo on startup?

Tags: bash, scripts, sudo, startup, systemd

I got a Lenovo Yoga 7i, there is a known issue with its audio card on the current kernels where it wont output sound through the speakers.

There is, however, a hackish solution described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_Yoga_7i#Speaker_audio) where, after doing the setup, you run this script and the audio works

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo rtcwake -m mem -s 1
while true
do
  echo -n -e '\x00' | padsp tee /dev/audio
  sleep 5
done
```

The problem with this script is that in order to run `rtcwake`, you seem to need to run it as `sudo`, meaning you need to input the password making it useless as a startup script. But running the script as `root` from the start means that the while loop outputs the error `tee: /dev/audio: Connection refused` over and over.

How can I run this script, that only uses parts of it as sudo, on startup from any user?

Comment: Yes. Read `man sudoers`, you can set up passwordless access to that single command.

Comment: What version Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

What may work is to split the script: run the `rtcwake -m mem -s 1` during startup as root. Nowadays, a crontab may be the most convenient way to do that (unless you fancy writing a systemd service):

```
sudo crontab -e
```

To open and edit the root crontab file, and add:

```
@reboot rtcwake -m mem -s 1
```

You then could run the next part in another script that you autostart on user login.